# Too many compound keys in sorting

Tags: node.js, mongodb

Let say I have 20 fields in collection. Need to sort collection data in asc order with all blanks/null must be lower.

For this issue solve we used extra 20 custom fields in $project, to move blanks/null to lower.

sorting stage level limit have 32 fields but we have now 40

How to solve sort mongodb collection like Excel sort.

Comment: You can overcome the limitation of 32 fields in the $sort stage and achieve a sorting behavior similar to Excel sort by splitting the sorting operation into multiple stages and merging the results.